# SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD spike on Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-group

I am about to lose my mind on this one.

We have a 3 server availability group from which our applications read from all 3 servers.  Runs great 99.9% of the time.  Every now and then we get a spike in SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD.  When this happens a lot of our queries timeout.  Usually doesn't last longer than a minute.  We have a task that captures wait stats every 2 minutes (image below).

8a is the primary server in the availability group.  As you can see, SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD spikes from 122,000 at 10:40 to 4,000,000 at 10:42 and back to 85,000 at 10:44.  The other servers spike to around 2,000,000.

These servers are all virtual.  8a and 8c are on the same host while 8b is in a different local datacenter.  Servers use the SAN in the datacenter in which they reside so 8a and 8c use the same SAN.

No jobs were running at the time.  The Server admin did not see any issues on the servers themselves.  The host for 8b CPU usage spiked from 43% at 10:40 to 70% at 1045 and the host for the other 2 spiked from 42% to 62% at the same time.  Both dropped back down at the 10:50 mark.

**I need ideas on what could cause this type of behavior and/or ideas on how to troubleshoot.**  I understand the SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD may be an indicator and not the problem itself.  I just know that when I start getting timeouts on these servers, SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD spikes and spikes high.  Thanks in advance for the ideas.

[image: Wait Stats Monitor]

Comment: I would investigate the cause of the CPU spike. The SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits are a byproduct of that. Could be parallel queries (which would also have CXPACKET waits) or even something outside of the SQL Server process.

Comment: That's my problem.  I can't figure that out.  We don't get notified until after everything is back to normal.  I don't know exactly what queries are running. This only last for around 1 minute and we don't have real time monitoring tools.

Comment: Consider creating an XE trace to capture long running batch and rpc completed events for forensics.

Comment: I usually ask the companies to invest in these 24/7 monitoring tools, it makes our job a lot easier as DBAs but when monitoring tools are not an option, using [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com/) comes handy, I usually setup a job to capture sp_whoIsActive every 10 seconds on the server. If for any reason it is not possible to run it 24/7, only do it for the time windows where you think you are having issues, you will learn a lot more about your server, some things may surprise you :)

Comment: We run a version of that every minute.  Problem is that when CPU spikes queries timeout.  That include sp_WhoIsActive.  I also can't think of a reason that the CPU spikes on all 3 hosts in the AG at the same time.  Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [read this article](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/sos_scheduler_yield/) by Paul Randal. It explain the `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` wait type. What cause the `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` to show up? Read it [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/sql-performance/knee-jerk-waits-sos-scheduler-yield).

Around the time of 1042am, try to execute the query below. From there check the query and query plan and analyze it from there.

```
    SELECT
    [er].[session_id],
    [es].[program_name],
    [est].text,
    [er].[database_id],
    [eqp].[query_plan],
    [er].[cpu_time]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests [er]
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions [es] ON
    [es].[session_id] = [er].[session_id]
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text ([er].[sql_handle]) [est]
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan ([er].[plan_handle]) [eqp]
WHERE
    [es].[is_user_process] = 1
    AND [er].[last_Wait_type] = N'SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD'
ORDER BY
    [er].[session_id];
GO
```

Comment: I would love to do that but I don't know when it is going to happen again so it is hard to do that.

Answer (score 0):

We exerienced the same today and it was due to a virtualization issue.
We had another VM on the same physical host which spiked to 100% CPU and due to overcommitment and missing reservation, took the database VM with it.
I think this is almost impossible to track down from within the Database / Database VM. The SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD waits were actually the whole VM waiting vor CPU cycles.